# Swift Style UIView Using CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I would like to natively style a UIView to match this image. I'm having a hard time adding the pointer to view. This is my code that I'm calling in ViewDidLoad:

```
func shapeView(sender: UIView){
    var corners: UIRectCorner = [.allCorners]

    let radius: CGFloat = 16
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: sender.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    sender.layer.mask = mask
}
```

Trying to replicate this pointer:

[image: Style]
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Try [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/) to create these kind of shapes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code generated with PaintCode:

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000)
let color2 = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000)

//// Rectangle Drawing
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(42, 32, 45, 40), cornerRadius: 7)
color2.setFill()
rectanglePath.fill()

var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(87, 45))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(99, 52))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(87, 59))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(87, 45))
bezierPath.closePath()
color.setFill()
bezierPath.fill()
```